# Filtering an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, windows-phone-7, observablecollection

When I bind a ListBox directly to an ObservableCollection I get the real-time updates displayed in my ListBox, but as soon as I add other LINQ methods in the mix my ListBox is no longer notified of any changes to the ObservableCollection.

Here, let me illustrate with an example;

```cs
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    ObservableCollection<String> Words = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.ItemsSource = Words;
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Words.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here I've added a Button and a ListBox to a simple Page, and clicking the button makes the new item appear immediately in the ListBox.

However, if I change from

```cs
        listBox1.ItemsSource = Words;
```

to

```cs
        listBox1.ItemsSource = Words.Where(w => w.Contains(":"));
```

the ListBox is no longer updated.

How can I add a "filter" between my ObservableCollection and the ListBox, and still get it to update without having to set the .ItemsSource again?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try using the CollectionViewSource like this:

```
WordsView = new CollectionViewSource();
WordsView.Filter += Words_Filter;
WordsView.Source = Words;

// ...
void Words_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item != null)
        e.Accepted = ((string)e.Item).Contains(":");
}
```

Comment: How about the binding between the ListBox and the CollectionViewSource? I can't use the .ItemsSource as before. Do I have to use .DataContext?

Comment: Sure you can, just set the ItemsSource to the WordsView.View property

Comment: @bendewey this solution is OK. But it's still very slow

Answer (score 6):

Why it does not work:

```
listBox1.ItemsSource = Words.Where(w => w.Contains(":"));
```

Your are not binding the ObservableCollection but the IEnumerable generated by Linq. This new "list" does not notify the ListBox about changes in the list.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `ICollectionView.Filter` property:

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Words);
view.Filter = WordFilter;

...


bool WordFilter(object o)
{
    string w = (string)o;
    return w.Contains(":")
}
```

Comment: Does it work in Windows Phone 7 as well? I can't find the GetDefaultView method on the static CollectionViewSource class.

Comment: @Frode, apparently not... This works in WPF; I checked that CollectionViewSource existed in Silverlight, but I didn't think of checking GetDefaultView... Another option is to create the CollectionViewSource explicitly in XAML, bind it to your collection, and handle the Filter event